# Generations paradox

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I have $2$ parents, $4$ grandparents, $8$ great grandparents, etc.

So, going back $N$ generations, I have $2^N$ great...great grandparents.

But $2^N$ is seriously divergent.  I only have to go back a small number of generations to exceed the total population of the earth!!

That's impossible, so we have a paradox.  What went wrong with the calculation?

Comment: some of those great...great grandparents are the same people

Comment: Someone commited incest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of those great...great grandparents are the same people

Comment: [This site agrees](http://dgmweb.net/Ancillary/OnE/NumberAncestors.html)